How can I pause the Puppeteer request, get the 2FA code from another API, then continue the request with the obtained code?
I am working on a web automation task using Puppeteer. My script is able to handle the regular login process smoothly, but I'm encountering difficulty when 2FA (Two-Factor Authentication) is required.
Here's the scenario I'm dealing with:

I launch Puppeteer and navigate to the login page.
I fill in the username and password fields and click the login button.
If the 2FA is required, I handle that case.

here's my code
export const Login = async (user) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
  await page.goto("https://www.example.com/login/");

  await page.waitForSelector("input[name=username]", { visible: true });
  await delay(100); // Adjust delay as needed
  await page.type("input[name=username]", user.username, { delay: 50 });

  await delay(100); // Adjust delay as needed
  await page.type("input[name=password]", user.password, { delay: 50 });

  await delay(100); // Adjust delay as needed
  // const [signin] = await page.$x('//button[contains(.,"Log in")]');
  // await signin.click({ delay: 30 });
  await page.click('button[type="submit"]');

  try {

    try {
      // Check if 2FA is required
      const requires2FA = await page.waitForSelector(
        'input[name="verificationCode"]'
      );

      if (requires2FA) {
        console.log("verificationCode field find");
        const message = await page.evaluate(
          () =>
            document.querySelector("#verificationCodeDescription").textContent
        );

        return {
          status: 201,
          message: `2FA Required! ${message}`,
        };
      }

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }

    
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
    

    console.log("Login successful");
    const cookies = await page.cookies();
    await saveCookies(user.username, cookies);

    return {
      status: 1,
      message: "Login successful",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Login failed:", error.message);
    return {
      status: 0,
      message: "Login failed:" + error.message,
    };
  }
};

how can I pause the Puppeteer request, obtain the 2FA code from another API, and then continue the request with the obtained code?

await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" }); looks spurious. It's hard to help since https://www.example.com/login/ isn't the actual site, so I can't reproduce the behavior. You can use userDataDir to avoid much of the auth, and readline to pause the script until the user presses Enter to proceed, or set a long enough timeout that the user can do the 2FA. Or is the 2FA automated by Node as well?

Thank you for correcting the unnecessary code. Yes, I utilized cookies to avoid repeated logins. Regarding automating the 2FA process, it's challenging since I receive the 2FA code via phone number. If I set a long timeout, my concern is how to resume the automation request after receiving the 2FA code from another API/frontend.

If the 2FA code is coming from another API, can you await the response? What is the trigger for the 2FA being done?

I have two routes: one for login. If 2FA is required, it returns a response indicating so, prompting me to display the OTP code field on my frontend. Once the user submits the OTP, I retrieve the code from another API. My challenge is how to proceed with the initial login request using the OTP code obtained from the frontend.

You might want to show that route and API call. It sounds like you'll need to break your Login function into (at least) two pieces. If the first call portion doesn't need 2FA, then call the second function and keep going with the scrape. Otherwise, if 2FA is required, pause work, hold state in memory, and respond to the client asking for the code. Then use the second route to accept the user's response, call the other API to get whatever info you need from that, and finally proceed with the scrape based on those responses. But I'll need to see this code to be able to help more specifically.

yes exactly, To share the complete code, could you please provide your GitHub handle?

Thanks, but I'll just wait for the question to have the minimal repro code.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Hi, here's the minimal repro code: https://github.com/hammadev/login-repro-code  Apologies for the delayed response; I was on holiday.

@ggorlen Did you get a chance to check it out?
